# Trouble with multiple regex options with Python re library

Tags: python, regex

I am using the python RE library (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). I am trying to search search a string for various substrings. I have the following function:

```
def checkformatch(search_str):

  to_find = re.compile("yes|[ +y +]|[^y +]")
  match_obj = to_find.search(search_str)
  which_word_matched = match_obj.group() if match_obj else ''
  return which_word_matched
```

the search string would look something like:

```
search_str = "blah fish cat dog yes haha y no"
```

I want to check for a word 'y' ( indicating yes) or yes

the first 2 options in:

```
re.compile("yes|[^y +]|[ +y +]")
```

work but the third does not. Can someone help me?

EDIT: I'm using re.compile because of its ability to use the '|' operator. I will probably need the option of searching for additional strings like "bob" or " what's up" in the future and I thought that this construct would give me "room to grow". Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It might help for you to explain what you think your regex "cases" mean.

Comment: You mean you want to search for `y` or `yes` on their own? Why not use `(^|\s)y(es)?(\s|$)`?

Comment: CB, I did : " I want to check for a word 'y' ( indicating yes) or yes "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply look for a conditional `yes` or `y`, with a word boundary:

```
re.compile(r'\b(yes|y)\b')
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/oL0vZ7

Comment: That's just too vague of a question to answer; you can write a regular expression to match all sorts of things. In this case, it matches what you have. If you want to change the criteria, then we can look at updating the expression.

Comment: You does seem to work including whitespace which is what I was going for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find instances of either `yes` or `y`, you probably want a regex that looks like this:

```
re.compile(r'\b(yes|y)\b')
```

That is, either `yes` or `y` in between word boundaries (e.g. whitespace)

---

Your regex (`yes|[^y +]|[ +y +]`) matches any of the following:

- "yes"
- any single character except a "y", " ", or "+"
- any single character that is a  "y", " ", or "+"

In other words, it matches any single character, which is probably not what you want.

cf. the output of compiling your regex with `re.DEBUG` on:

```
branch 
  literal 121 # y
  literal 101 # e
  literal 115 # s
or
  in 
    negate None
    literal 121 # y
    literal 32  # <space>
    literal 43  # +
or
  in 
    literal 32  # <space>
    literal 43  # +
    literal 121 # y
    literal 32  # <space>
    literal 43  # +
```